# Firebase-firestore querying the selected field values using Android FirestoreRecyclerAdapter not working

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

[image: firestore screenshot]i am trying to query the selected document from **firestore collections** based on field value.
single **WHERE** condition is working fine. but multiple documents not able to fetch from **Firestore** using single query.

Code:

```
Query query = db.collection("users").whereEqualTo("email","xyz@gmail.com",);//here how to add multiple emails as a input.


FirestoreRecyclerOptions<User> response = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<User>()
                .setQuery(query, User.class)
                .build();

        firestoreRecyclerAdapter = new FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<User, FriendsHolder>(response) {
            @Override
            public void onBindViewHolder(FriendsHolder holder, int position, User model)
            {
                    holder.nameView.setText(model.getDisplayName());
                    holder.statusView.setText(model.getStatus());
                       
            }

            @Override
            public FriendsHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup group, int i) {
                View view = LayoutInflater.from(group.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.users_view_item, group, false);

                return new FriendsHolder(view);
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
                Log.e("error", e.getMessage());
            }
        };


        firestoreRecyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        recyclerViewfriendList.setAdapter(firestoreRecyclerAdapter);
        firestoreRecyclerAdapter.startListening();
    }
```

kindly help me thanks in advance.

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot.

Comment: @AlexMamo please check the image. i want to fetch the multiple email data based on my where condition

Comment: Please also edit your question and add the content of your `User` class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how to add multiple emails as a input.

I think you are looking for `in` condition

```js
Query query = db.collection("users").whereIn("email", Arrays.asList("xyz@gmail.com", "abc@gmail.com"));
```

- `in` query returns documents where the given field matches any of the comparison values

Comment: can u please add the same query for realtime database